# Gradient Legend Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, gradient

I'm new to python. My code reads in a csv as a dataframe and then loops through the columns and plots each as a bar chart on top of each other. What I would like to do is add a gradient legend to the plot that ranges from blue alpha =0.01 to blue alpha =1.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import datetime

data = pd.read_csv("SomePath\Data.csv")
data.iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[:, 0])

year=pd.DatetimeIndex(data.iloc[:, 0]).year
df =pd.DataFrame(data)

X = year

for i in range(2,len(df.columns)):
    Y = list(df.iloc[:, i])
    plt.bar(X, Y, color='blue',alpha=0.01)

plt.title("Title")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(X),max(X)+1,1))
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

Comment: Did you consider something like a discrete colorbar? Consider creating a ScalarMappable and use that to make the colorbar. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom legend using a [LinearSegmentedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

x = range(20)
y = np.array(range(240,260))

kwargs = {
    'color': 'blue',
    'alpha': 0.3
}

plt.bar(x, y, **kwargs)
plt.bar(x, y*0.5, **kwargs)
plt.bar(x, y*2, **kwargs)

# From the docs: Create colormap from linear mapping segments
# segmentdata argument is a dictionary with a red, green and 
# blue entries. Each entry should be a list of x, y0, y1 tuples,
# forming rows in a table. Entries for alpha are optional.
cdict = {
    'red': [
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) # red always 0
    ],
    'green': [
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), # green always 0
    ],
    'blue': [
        (0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) # blue always 1
     ], 
    'alpha': [
        (0.0, 0.01, 0.01),
        (1.0, 1.0,  1.0) # alpha increases from 0.01 to 1
     ], 
} 

# colourbar from custom cdict
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('blue', cdict, N=256)
plt.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(Normalize(0,1), cmap))
```

Resulting image

[image]